# Create list in python without mentioning it?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a function that splits a list of strings into a list with multiple lists (like a 2D list). But I'm stuck when I need to make a new list in the output list. I also can't mention/create the lists beforehand since I want to be able to determine how many "sublists" I want (`splitn`).

```
list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

ListSplit(list, 2)

[["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
```

```
def ListSplit(list, splitn):
    output = []
    count = 0
    for element in list:
        count += 1
        output.append(element)
        if count >= splitn:
            output.append("new sublist")
            count = 0
    return output
```

I'm sure there's some simple way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: What is the problem/question here? Please be more specific.

Comment: " I also can't mention/create the lists beforehand since I want to be able to determine how many "sublists" I want" This doesn't really make any sense. You basically need your final list that you will return, and then use *other* lists that you will append to this final list.

Comment: so, `output.append("new sublist")` should be `output.append(some_list)` where `some_list` is a list that you've beein building up inside the loop, and doing `some_list.append(element)` not `output.append(element)`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use slicing instead to achieve list grouping

example:

```
def list_split(l, n):
 x = []
 for i in range(0, len(l)-n +1,n):
   x.append(l[i:i+n])
 return x
```

sample output:

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
list_split(l,3)
list_split(l,2)
```

will yield

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F']]
[['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range` to count by `splitn` lengths and split the list from there

```
def ListSplit(the_list, splitn):
    return [the_list[i:i+splitn] for i in range(0, len(the_list), splitn)]

list = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
out = ListSplit(list, 2)
print(out)
```